# Fixed positioning woes on tablet devices

Tags: responsive-design

I'm experiencing the annoying issue were mobile/tablet devices don't support `position: fixed` (iOS 5+ and Android 3+ thankfully do) on a single page site I'm working on where a fixed position main nav is really important for the UX.

After reading [Brad Frosts](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/) excellent article about this I decided to take his advice and use **user agent sniffing** to target iOS and Android making the fixed main nav visible and for all other mobile devices it is not visible and instead I'm inserting a link after each main section to the main nav in the footer, not great but good enough. However in my desktop media query: **1024px +** (I'm building the site 'Mobile First') I need to make the fixed main nav visible for desktop users but this affects many tablet devices that don't support `position: fixed` e.g. Samsung Galaxy but do support CSS media queries.

There just doesn't seem an easy way to get all the non-iOS/Android tablet devices fixed without getting into JavaScript solutions mentioned in Brad's article which I'd rather avoid for the same reasons Brad has pointed out or get into more messy **user agent sniffing** which again I'd rather avoid. At least I've got iOS and Android working.

**EDIT:** one thing I could do is up the desktop media query to **1366px +** which seems to be the most common desktop resolution ([see here](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/11/move-over-1024x768-the-most-popular-screen-resolution-on-the-web-is-now-1366x768/)), this won't hit most tablets as it seems their max screen size is typically **1280px**. A bit risky though as many desktop users will shrink their browser viewports resulting in the fixed main nav not being visible making the site hard to use and I think this use case would be greater than tablet users?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing all the right things, or at least are worried about what I would call the right things. So I have to wonder, "Is it form following function, or function following form?" Seems like 99% of this would solve itself, if you reexamined your code for a more friendly design. You seem to be chasing a nav bar. I'll bet your visitors are much more concerned with your content. FWIW

Comment: Good comments and luckily these days I'm a lot more practical about how I develop websites esp. responsive ones, i.e. know when to step away and try not to provide a perfect solution as in most cases it's just not possible AND that the main focus is on the content. The reason I'm chasing the nav bar so much is because it's a single page site (I wouldn't give it a 2nd thought if it wasn't) therefore the page is *very* tall so for touch users esp. it can get a bit tedious to get around the page e.g. a lot of swiping. [cont..]

Comment: [cont...] They're ways to reduce the page height yes by introducing horizontal scrolling or expandable/collapsible sections but this was never the original plan for the site and I did not want to get into a lot of heavy jQuery dev as the site needs to perform well. I've spent many hours trying to adjust the design to come up with an easy way for non-iOS/Android users to easily navigate the page and the best I could do was offer them a link to the main nav in the footer at the end of each section which as I said isn't too bad and as you said I'd hope they're much more concerned with [cont...]

Comment: [cont...] the content but some sections are very tall esp. when everything is linerased as it is for mobile and some tablet devices. Really the no.1 solution is a `position: fixed;` nav bar. I've just decided to not worry about it as much as it's only going to affect tablets in the 1280px + res range, and wait for the relevant mobile browsers to implement `position: fixed;` which hopefully won't be too long seeing how fast they release new versions. Cheers.

Comment: With your comments, I may suggest taking a look at iScroll. It is a javascript (not jQuery) addition, but it has proved useful for me on the last couple of mobile/tablet sites. Very small footprint, and easy enough to configure. Would also allow you to 'fix' a header/nav (mine have always been at the top of the page). Cheers.

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look at iScroll.

Comment: Have you looked at using Modernizr (http://modernizr.com). It a great Javascript library that detects the availability of native implementations. The Css class 'html.no-touch' or 'html.touch' can be a really useful tool. It is not 100% accurate as it will only indicates if the browser supports touch events, which does not necessarily reflect a touchscreen device. However this in addition to your current measures my be useful.